# Is there a difference between using の and ある in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence

On the Wikipedia entry for jurassic park it reads as follows :

> 現実では、2012年のマードック大学の研究によって、DNAの半減期が521年で、DNAの復元に必要な長さのDNA断片が残るのは約100万年前までと推定され、恐竜の絶滅から約6500万年が経過した現代では、生息当時のDNAを用いた恐竜の再生は実現不可能であると判明した

Saying that dinosaur can not be revived since a DNA of sufficient lenght - for revival-could at best survive for 1 million years while dinosaurs have been extinct for at least 65 millions years .
What i find troublesome is this sentece:

> DNAの復元に必要な長さのDNA断片が残るのは約100万年前までと推定され

The original English that this is translated of reads : “

> If the decay rate is accurate then we predict that DNA fragments of
> sufficient length will preserve in frozen fossil bone from around one
> million years in age,”  .

should  not the translation be somthing like DNAの復元に必要な長さのあるDNA断片が残るのは/ DNAの復元に必要な長さあるDNA断片が残るのは ?
Because from i what i understand  DNAの復元に必要な長さのDNA断片が残るのは translate to : " and it is estimated that DNA fragments of the length required for DNA restoration will only remain until about one million years ago" .

Comment: What is wrong with 長さの? Even in English we say the segment **of** the required length, instead of the segment **which has** the required length. Isn't the former more natural even in English? Japanese is the same logic. Something can be **of** a certain length, but it sounds awkward to **have(own/possess)** a certain length.

Comment: 長さのある is fine but 長さある sounds broken.